# How to convert string "20220202072442" to date and time in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to convert string to date and time, from "20220202072442" to 02-02-2022 07:24:42

Comment: They seem two string to me, look into the String#substring() menthod. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("20220202072442", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))`

Comment: @Juan - Doing this conversion using substring is clumsy.